# How to relate categories with subcategory i.e. tag in rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning ruby on rails and i am creating a blogger app. In which i have many users and users can have many blogs. Now I want to create blogs on the basis of category. But i also want category having subcategory i.e tag. On the basis of category and subcategory user can search blogs. If there is no subcategory then it'll insert into subcategory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if you want to keep things in separate tables then you can have a chain of association between models like this:

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end
```

Post Model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Category Model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
  has_many :subcategories
end
```

SubCategory Model

```
class SubCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make a new model for the categories. That new model could have Self-Referential Associations to itself, so you could associate sub-categories (what I called children below) or parent categories.

```rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category'
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
end
```

This would leave the flexibility to add associations to users, depending if you want the categories belong to users or if they are across the app.

Comment: thanks @csexton but i want a new table for subcategories

Comment: That would be easier then, a standard has_may to a new model.